# How to use Oracle as an embedded database for running unit tests in maven?

Tags: oracle, maven, junit

I have an application for which the prod/test/qa database is only Oracle.
Furthermore, I suspect SQL queries to be Oracle-specific.
And unfortunatly, this application has second to no unit tests.

As a consequence, I would like to implement to unit tests, specifically regarding the search component (which obviously performs lots of Oracle operations, including table creation).

Usually, when I want to run tests, I start an embedded database (HSQL, as an example), run my tests on that database, and let it fade away when my tests end.

Due to my lack of confidence on the standardization level of this application, I would prefer to run tests on an Oracle database. As a consequence, I would like to start oracle database when my tests start, fill it with some test datan and stop it on test end. How can I do that in a maven context ?

Comment: Hint: be precise about wording. I think the vast majority of IT professionals would not consider a test that needs a running database ... to be a **unit** test. Better call it a functional or integration test; just in order to prevent misconceptions for everybody around you. True **unit** tests run at compile time; they only need your compiled classes and JUnit - not some embedded database, file system, web service, socket, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand you want Oracle, but you may also try with h2 using oracle mode flag

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=Oracle
```

I have the same need in most of my projects, and this is the closest to Oracle I found. You can define **aliases** for the few missing functions.

Comment: How do you alias `dense_rank`?

Comment: I don't think it can be done, since dense_rank doesn't follow standard SQL format (ie: DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)):  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/OJkQaoWFHeM

Answer (score 2):

You can use [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to start any application during Maven lifecycle, including a full Oracle instance. However, you still need to have it installed on the builder, etc. which complicates the solution quite a bit.

So what we've done in another project:

1. Define a unique build name as Maven property (default to username for local builds; let CI provide this via `-D`, e.g., on Bamboo you can include build plan key and number)
2. Connect to a shared Oracle instance on our infrastructure
3. Create a new scheme based on the defined build name
4. Update the new empty scheme with DDL (we use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) in production, so this part is easy)
5. Run integration tests
6. Drop scheme in post-integration-test phase (since builds can be stopped manually or hang, it's still necessary to have some kind of automatic DB cleanup for stale schemes)

You can use [sql-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html) for executing SQL scripts. Or [flyway-maven-plugin](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/) if using Flyway.